# Problem integrating the OpenAI API with my website using XAMPP and PHP

Tags: php, curl, xampp, openai-api

I am creating a local website that makes use of the OpenAI API using XAMPP and HTML/CSS and PHP. I have implemented a page to enter a question and display the answer from the API, but the result has no relation to the question asked. I am looking for help to solve this problem. Here is my php code (it works with another file calling it).

Thanks in advance for your help.
PS: I voluntarily removed the api key when I posted the request on stack overflow

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

```
<?php

$apiKey = 'sk-';
$modelId = 'text-davinci-002';

$prompt = "";
$temperature = 0.5;
$maxTokens = 256;
$topP = 1;
$frequencyPenalty = 0;
$presencePenalty = 0;


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\"model\": \"".$modelId."\",
  \"prompt\": \"".$prompt."\",
  \"temperature\": ".$temperature.",
  \"max_tokens\": ".$maxTokens.",
  \"top_p\": ".$topP.",
  \"frequency_penalty\": ".$frequencyPenalty.",
  \"presence_penalty\": ".$presencePenalty."}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$apiKey,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $result = json_decode($response);
  echo $result->choices[0]->text;
}

?>
```

I tried several solutions such as changing the API model and rewriting the code, but I could not solve the problem. I am looking for help to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how the results obtained differ from expected and why you are baking your own JSON data for the POST request rather than using `json_encode`? Nobody can test your code without an api key  presumably so the more information you can give the better

Comment: For example, when I ask him "1+1" he answers me: "What are you?" I looked around the room, searching for someone or something. I didn't find anyone before I looked at the bed, where my family had left me when they had left for the night. My bed, my clothing, my bedtime stories. I cashed myGhosts card and set up a time for when they would be allowed to see me. When I woke up, there were people in the room. People who were never meant to be there in the first place. People who were supposed to be gone. They were still in the room, waiting to take me away."

Comment: Clearly the response ( if that is what you posted in comment ) is utter nonsense. Can you provide a link to the exact documentation that is relevant to the above code?